# Modify table using treewalker

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a treewalker to locate a table on page, insert a column, then populate the cells in that column based on the value in each rows 1st cell.  I've done a lot of research and I keep failing.  Any hits to push me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```js
document.ondblclick = addElement;
var i = 1;
function addElement () { 

    var allTextNodes = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT),
    // some temp references for performance
    tmptxt,
    tmpnode,
    // compile the RE and cache the replace string, for performance
    cakeRE = "Investment"
    replaceValue = "TestReplace";
    var allElementNodes = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);

    // iterate through all text nodes
while (allTextNodes.nextNode()) {
    tmpnode = allTextNodes.currentNode;
    tmptxt = tmpnode.nodeValue;
    tmpnode.nodeValue = tmptxt.replace(cakeRE, replaceValue);
}

    // iterate through all Element nodes
while (allElementNodes.nextNode()) {
    tmpnode = allElementNodes.currentNode;

    //I know this is not even close to real code but I think it explains what i'm trying to do

    IF (tmpnode.tagvalue = "table")
    { 
    tmpnode.insertcolumn
    }
    If (tempnode.tagvalue = "tr" && Row.contains("Active"))
    {
    pupulate the cell from the previously created column with "Active Pending";
    }

    
}
}
```

```js
function PopulateTable() {
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    for(var i = 0; i< rows.length; i++ ) {
        var firstColumn = rows[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        //do your data aggregation here
        var newCell = document.createElement("td");
        newCell.innerHTML = "some data";//create row here
        rows[i].appendChild(newCell);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be going about this in the wrong way. I would advise against using a treewalker in this particular case. Instead you could do something much simpler like so:

```
function PopulateTable() {
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    for(var i = 0; i< rows.length; i++ ) {
        var firstColumn = rows[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        //do your data aggregation here
    }
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    newRow.innerHTML = //create row here
    table.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'll give this a try, i'm fiddling around with it now.

Comment: Hi Thomas, the newRow method did work.  I am hoping to add a new cell to each row, something like this (new code snipped added above).